# Nontype error while iterating json in djagon template

Tags: python, django

I need to iterate json in my django template. I receive nontype error while attempting to do this. the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

```
 context["reserved"] = json.dumps(reserved, sort_keys=True)         
 return render(request, 'users_templates/reservations.html', context)


{% for date,time in reserved.items|loadjson %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                                <td>{{date}}</td>
                                <td>Pitt</td>
                                <td>35</td>
                                <td>test</td>
                            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It seems to me that dumping a json (list or dict -> str) in the view and then loading a json (str -> list or dict) is not necessary. Just add `reserved` to the context and use it as a `dict` or `list` in the template.

Comment: @MarcosModenesi deleting tag and iterating it like for date,time in reserved.items, returns nothing

Comment: I suggest for getting help you edit your question and add what is the value of the `reserved` variable (what your suppose it has and / or the validated content) and what is `loadjson`  (where does the filter come from: is it django? is it yours?). Also, copy and paste the full traceback.